# How come spacing is different between button and label same width and height?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good afternoon, I am using a blank label for spacing between buttons to keep them in the correct position and I am wondering how come the size of an ASP label and button are diffent even know they are the same size? See below:

```
   protected void PopulateAddButton(string ID)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "add";
        btn.Visible = false;
        btn.Width = 40;
        btn.Height = 20;
        btn.ID = "addbutton_" + ID;
        btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(addButton_Click);
        pnlAddButton.Controls.Add(btn);

        //preserve the space between buttons
        Label btnSpacer = new Label();
        btnSpacer.Width = 40;
        btnSpacer.Height = 20;
        btnSpacer.ID = "btnSpacer_" + ID;
        btnSpacer.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        pnlAddButton.Controls.Add(btnSpacer);
    }
```

You'll see below that the spacing is good when I use buttons as spacers and that it's bad when I use labels as spacers. I want to use labels since all my data is not in a table rather, panels.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out layout in dev tools to see where extra space coming from. Search for "css reset" to remove browser default margins/padding from elements.

Comment: Keep in mind that buttons are "special".  A button in XP looks different from Win7 looks different from MacOS.  If you are concerned about cohesion, I'd use an ImageButton instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I had to set the label text equal to "&nbsp" Thanks all!